# Format mysql TIMESTAMP AS x days, x hours, x minutes, x seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have table that saves tickets information, and I want to know how long time the ticket stayed in a certain pool. I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME((MAX(T.transfareDate)-MAX(TMAX.transfareDate)),'%k hours, %i minutes,    %s seconds') AS 'Time to repair' 
 FROM  aims_item_group_transfare T
 LEFT JOIN  aims_item_group_transfare TMAX ON T.item_id = TMAX.item_id AND    TMAX.toGroupId=20
 WHERE T.fromGroupId =20
```

It works fine, now I want to get in addition the number of days as following:
Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds

Any body can help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`period_diff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff) to calculate the difference in months.  Note that the function requires a parameter in `"YYYYMM"` string format, not a date.

```
select  concat(
            period_diff(
                date_format(DateDiff, '%Y%m')
            ,   '197001') -- 1970-01 = Start of UnixTime
        ,   ' months '
        ,   date_format(
                DateDiff,
                '%k hours, %i minutes, %s seconds')
        ) as TimeToRepair
from    (
        select  from_unixtime(
                    max(T.transfareDate) - max(TMAX.transfareDate) 
                ) as DateDiff
        from    aims_item_group_transfare T
        left join
                aims_item_group_transfare TMAX 
        on      T.item_id = TMAX.item_id 
                and TMAX.toGroupId = 20
        group by
                T.item_id
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55d34/1/0)

Comment: Hi Andomar,
Thank you for your post, I still want the eclipsed time in Days:Hours:Minutes:Sesconds. Please keep in mind that I save the time in timestamp format
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your kind note.  The example assumes the table column stores timestamps (see the SQL Fiddle link at the bottom.)  It should be easy to adjust the exact time format-- I'll leave that as an exercise.